# bootstrap-select set option text with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have issue with set up option text from ajax url.

For example i have url `http://localhost:5000/api/test/calgroups`

In this url i can see `json` list of all group names (CAN BE MORE)

```
["tes1","tes2","tes3","tes4","tes5","tes6"]
```

but i cant found some info how to set up, my multiselect function text's i wanna make like this

```
    <select class="selectpicker" name="MultiSelectGroup" id="ms1" multiple>
        <option id="gruop" >test1</option>
        <option id="gruop" >test2</option>
        <option id="gruop" >test3</option>
... (ant more)
    </select>
```

My code for get text value in alert field ( its not necessary to show, but maybe it will help)

```
$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function () {

    selectedServices = $.map($(this).find("option:selected"), function(o) { return o["label"]; });
alert(selectedServices)


});
```

So how to set up my option fields with value from ajax link? All help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch you values with ajax and insert them as options like so:

(Please keep in mind that the fetching of the values is mocked here, it just returns the array)

```js
async function getValuesWithAjax() {
  return ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
}

$(function() {

  getValuesWithAjax().then(values => {
    values.forEach(value => {
      $(".selectpicker").append($("<option>")
        .val(value)
        .html(value)
      );
    });
  });


  $('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
    selectedServices = $(this).val();
    alert(selectedServices)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" name="MultiSelectGroup" id="ms1" multiple>
</select>
```

Comment: thank for help, but maybe possible to do without async function? and i have question then   ```var url = '/api/v1/calgroups/'
        return url;``` its not working for me, maybe u know why?

Comment: You are trying to load an array from a URL, simply returning the URL does not load the data. You should fetch the data using `XMLHttpRequest`. Fetching data from an external resource is always asynchronous.

Comment: so, in my case will be     ```xhttp.open("GET", "/api/test/calgroups", true);
        return xhttp;``` if im right have problem with link then link is ```/api/test/calgroups``` working fine, but request make it ```/api/test/calgroups/``` then link not working

Comment: Please create a new question for dealing with API requests in an html page.